# Inconsistent/ not persistent behavior of Gameobjects in deployed Vuforia Engine/ Unity AR app

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, ar-foundation, vuforia-cloud-recognition

I'm experiencing the following issue. I'm building an AR app with unity 2022.2.10, Vuforia Engine 10.14.4 and the AR Foundation. While I'm building to an IOS device, I experience inconsistent/ not persistent spatial behavior of the game objects.
Whenever I open my Unity project, the behavior and placement of my game objects looks right and works without any issues in the game/ simulator view. However, when I try to test the app on my mobile device the appearance and behavior of the game objects (the AR content) differs from the game/ scene/ simulator view in unity.
Does anybody has a solution to the explained issue or could point me towards resources that could help me solve the issue?

I built the unity project successfully, opened it it Xcode and deployed in on to my phone. I was expecting the game objects (AR content) to behave as in the scene view to create a persistent, spatial AR experience.
However, when testing the app inside the physical space of my area target I face multiple issues such as a random disappearance of the game objects (AR content) and behaviors of the game objects that differ from my scene/ game view in unity.